# Daily / Monthly websites backups?

Tags: backups

Do you usually perform a daily backup of websites of small local business ?
Isn't a monthly backup more appropriate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do daily backups, just because there's not really a big difference between daily or weekly or monthly except a little change in the crontab and the amount of data that's lost in the case of a problem. :-)

Database dump, and then the whole directory where the site + dump resides gets rsnapshot'ed to another server. Takes a few seconds each night, doesn't cost me a dime, but I can sleep at night.

A backup that requires any manual action should be reconsidered. Automate everything, and use the available tools (rsync, etc.) and you'll be able to do daily backups without any sweat.

Your customers **will** like it.

Comment: If it's e-commerce, or an active CMS type informational site, daily database backup is highly appropriate, if you have a good hosting provider, multiple versioned backups will be done every day with a preservation window dependent on your service level. Boutique sites that are largely static content may get away with monthly. It's too easy to cron this stuff and pull to external storage.

Answer (score 1):

The rhythm of backups depends of the rhythm of the website update : new content, updated content, scripts updates... The less resources consuming is to apply different delay to your website parts.

For example a page with a photo is added 2 times a week you can do a database, and images folder backup every 3 days. You update script plugins every month, you do a backup of your plugins directory every month.

There are tools like [Website 2 Backup](http://website2backup.com) to do automated, encrypted and selected website files and databases backups stored on email, ftp, or on web hosting.